# HTML element scroll UNDER another element

Tags: html, css

I have a title / button bar at the top of my page.
I also have a Table, which extends downward.

When I scroll, the table overlaps the title bar, which remains at the top of the screen at all times.

How do I make it so that the table to goes UNDER the title bar, instead of on top of it?

Comment: Change the `z-index` value..? Include relevant HTML/CSS here. A [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net) would be helpful too.

Comment: Show strips of your code HTML and CSS file please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your title bar stays in the same position on the screen, even when you scroll then you must be using:

```
#title-bar{
    position: fixed
}
```

try instead:

```
#title-bar{
    position: fixed
    z-index: 100
}

table {
    z-index:0
}
```

The z-index value will make your table slide under your title-bar.